# Java chatprogram, infinit loop stops

Tags: java, multithreading, chat

I have to build a chat program.
There is the server class, the client class and two threads to write and receive messages.
the two threads should run in an infinite loop and check all the time if there is an input and print that input afterwards.

But my program works for just one round. So the server and the client can write one single message, afterwards it stops and does not check for another message. Why does the thread not start again from the begin when it's never interrupted? --> see the code beneath
I hope you know what my problem is, it's quite hard for me to describe.

Thread to read a new Message

```
public class MsgWriter extends Thread  {

    private Socket s;

    public MsgWriter(Socket s){
        this.s = s;
    }
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
    OutputStream out = null;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Scanner input;
    while(!interrupted()){
        try{
        synchronized(s){

        input = new Scanner (System.in);

            out = s.getOutputStream();

         writer = new PrintWriter(out);
         String toserver = input.nextLine();
         writer.write(toserver);
         writer.flush();
         System.out.println("me: " + toserver);

        }
         try {
            Thread.sleep((int) (100 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Thread to check if there is a new message and prints it.

```
public class MsgReader extends Thread {


    Socket s;

    public MsgReader(Socket s){
        this.s = s;

    }


    public void run()  {
        int i = 0;
    while (!interrupted()) {
        try{
        synchronized(s){

        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String s = null;
        while((s=reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("d");
        }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int) (100 * 1));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        }

    }

    }
```

The Server class starts a new server and waits for a client, afterwards it starts the two threads. The same with the client class, it connects to the server and starts the threads.

Comment: What is the `interrupted()` method doing?

Comment: just to check if the thread should be continue working i think.
thread.interrupted() is the same as thread.stop() i guess (just read it in a forum to use if for the loop in a thread)

Comment: Debugging tip: Either step through it with a debugger, or intersperse it with print statements to find out where it breaks out or hangs.

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill to have. If you have more information, I can try to help you more, but as it is, this is the most I can do.

Comment: thanks a lot, i think i will be able to find the problem with the print method. i have to admit, i'm a beginner and never worked with the debugger. 
i guess my question is not very clear isn't it? i'm a bit confused why already 3 people downvoted my post.

Comment: The community here is not very noob friendly, most people don't appreciate questions that they could solve in a couple of seconds themselves with a debugger.

Comment: i tried it an figured out that the loop stops in the MsgReader class when it has to start the next loop -->  while((s=reader.readLine()) != null) 
it stops earlier when i try to check if reader.readLine() != null by using a System.out 
but again i have no idea why it is hanging at this possition

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thowing an exception somewhere. In your catch blocks, print the error.

```
try {

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: i copied the code in every catch block but there is no error message.
it just prints one time the message f.e. me:that is a message
and stops then.